# Delete only dependent table record in Entity Framework in TPT mapping

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got a problem with deleting entity only from dependant table when entity in base table should be untouched. Here is a simple schema of my class and entities hierarchy:

[image]

My question is how can I delete only record from `ActivityInvoice` and leave record in Invoice table. For example, I've got in Invoice table record with InvoiceID = 3 and in `ActivityInvoice` record with same `InvoiceID` and some additional data. Now I want to delete record from `ActivityInvoice` with `InvoiceID` = 3 and leave record with `InvoiceID` = 3 in `Invoice` table untouched.

My example classes:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

    public string Field{ get; set; }
}

public class ActivityInvoice : Invoice
{
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }

    public decimal AdditionalField1 { get; set; }

    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

The following code will unfortunately delete both records, `ActivityInvoice` and `Invoice`.

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int invoiceID)
{
    ActivityInvoice activityinvoice = db.ActivityInvoices.Find(invoiceID);

    db.ActivityInvoices.Remove(activityinvoice);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Your problem implies that `ActivityInvoice` is not really an `Invoice` (and shouldn't derive from it), but rather it is `InvoiceActivity` that only contain some additional data *associated* with an `Invoice`.

Comment: haim770 is right. As for EF, your `ActivityInvoice` is just one invoice. If somehow they are separate entities you should model them as a 1-0..1 association.

Comment: Fortunately the concept had changed and now I've got one to many relationship :)
@haim770, Gert - thanks for your answers.